# How to initialise UIView in xcode project

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to achieve an animation very similar to the android's native  circle spinning in my xcode project

[image]

I found a class that achieves something very similar to this

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class SpinnerView : UIView {

    override var layer: CAShapeLayer {
        get {
            return super.layer as! CAShapeLayer
        }
    }

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAShapeLayer.self
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layer.fillColor = nil
        layer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.lineWidth = 3
        setPath()
    }

    override func didMoveToWindow() {
        animate()
    }

    private func setPath() {
        layer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds.insetBy(dx: layer.lineWidth / 2, dy: layer.lineWidth / 2)).cgPath
    }

    struct Pose {
        let secondsSincePriorPose: CFTimeInterval
        let start: CGFloat
        let length: CGFloat
        init(_ secondsSincePriorPose: CFTimeInterval, _ start: CGFloat, _ length: CGFloat) {
            self.secondsSincePriorPose = secondsSincePriorPose
            self.start = start
            self.length = length
        }
    }

    class var poses: [Pose] {
        get {
            return [
                Pose(0.0, 0.000, 0.7),
                Pose(0.6, 0.500, 0.5),
                Pose(0.6, 1.000, 0.3),
                Pose(0.6, 1.500, 0.1),
                Pose(0.2, 1.875, 0.1),
                Pose(0.2, 2.250, 0.3),
                Pose(0.2, 2.625, 0.5),
                Pose(0.2, 3.000, 0.7),
            ]
        }
    }

    func animate() {
        var time: CFTimeInterval = 0
        var times = [CFTimeInterval]()
        var start: CGFloat = 0
        var rotations = [CGFloat]()
        var strokeEnds = [CGFloat]()

        let poses = type(of: self).poses
        let totalSeconds = poses.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.secondsSincePriorPose }

        for pose in poses {
            time += pose.secondsSincePriorPose
            times.append(time / totalSeconds)
            start = pose.start
            rotations.append(start * 2 * .pi)
            strokeEnds.append(pose.length)
        }

        times.append(times.last!)
        rotations.append(rotations[0])
        strokeEnds.append(strokeEnds[0])

        animateKeyPath(keyPath: "strokeEnd", duration: totalSeconds, times: times, values: strokeEnds)
        animateKeyPath(keyPath: "transform.rotation", duration: totalSeconds, times: times, values: rotations)

        animateStrokeHueWithDuration(duration: totalSeconds * 5)
    }

    func animateKeyPath(keyPath: String, duration: CFTimeInterval, times: [CFTimeInterval], values: [CGFloat]) {
        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: keyPath)
        animation.keyTimes = times as [NSNumber]?
        animation.values = values
//        animation.calculationMode = .linear
        animation.duration = duration
        animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        layer.add(animation, forKey: animation.keyPath)
    }

    func animateStrokeHueWithDuration(duration: CFTimeInterval) {
        let count = 36
        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "strokeColor")
        animation.keyTimes = (0 ... count).map { NSNumber(value: CFTimeInterval($0) / CFTimeInterval(count)) }
        animation.values = (0 ... count).map {
            UIColor(hue: CGFloat($0) / CGFloat(count), saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1).cgColor
        }
        animation.duration = duration
//        animation.calculationMode = .linear
        animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        layer.add(animation, forKey: animation.keyPath)
    }

}
```

My question is how do i actually use that animation to show it in the view controller ?
Maybe even direct me to somewhere to research

Comment: https://github.com/bestiosdeveloper/PKLoader try this link

Comment: Edit: removed xcode tag. It's not relevant to the question

Answer (score 0):

In regards to using this exact class you would do this in your view controller class

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        showSpinnerView()
    }

    func showSpinnerView()
    {
        let spinnerView = SpinnerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:100, height: 100))
        self.view.addSubView(view: spinnerView)
    }
}
```

this will add the spinner view to the ViewControllers view. The CGRect you create when initialising `SpinnerView` will have to be the rect of where you want the thing to be but this is how to create and add it to your view

In this example as soon as the view loads it calls show spinner view but I assume you trigger some event that requires a loading type animation, in this case your spinner so just call show spinner view there.

Alternatively you can add it to your view controllers view in the view did load and set `spinnerView.isHidden = true` and then when the event happens that you want to a show progress spinner for just set `spinnerView.isHidden = false` (obviously in this case `spinnerView` would have to be a member variable so that you are able to access its properties from other functions

Comment: i cannot do the, self.vier.addsubview, i cannot do a self.view from a uiviewcontroller